# SQL server concatenate date and time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two columns which are "datetime" type in SQL server. However, one columns contains the valid date I need and the other one contains the time(hour, min,..) only.

How can I extract the date from the first column and the time from the last column and concatenate them together into a valid datetime column.

What I have tried:

```
select 
[Created on],
[Created At],
LEFT([Created On],11),
RIGHT([Created At],8),
LEFT([Created On],11) + RIGHT([Created At],8)
from..
```

However, the output makes sense but I want it to be a valid timestamp type in military format as the first and second columns. 
How can I do it?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the data type is `timestamp` and not `datetime`?  Or are they varchar() columns that happen to be in a particular format?

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: @GordonLinoff sorry sir... they are datetime format, I am modifying the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some google and this solution below works for me.

```
select 
[Created on],
[Created At],
CAST(Convert(date, [Created on]) as datetime) + CAST(Convert(time, [Created At]) as datetime),
LEFT([Created On],11) + RIGHT([Created At],8)
from [VERICAL$Purch_ Inv_ Header] 
where [Posting Date] > '2014-02-01
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try using this expression:-

```
select
DATEADD(MILLISECOND,datepart(MILLISECOND,created_at),
DATEADD(SECOND,datepart(SECOND,created_at),
DATEADD(minute,datepart(minute,created_at),
DATEADD(HOUR,datepart(hour,created_at),created_on))))
from ..
```

It actually finds the time part from the `created at` column and adds to `created on`

Answer (score 0):

Grab relevant pieces of date and time from the appropriate column using [DATEPART](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx), and piece back together using [DATETIMEFROMPARTS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213233.aspx) (if on SQL Server 2012).

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5ebd9/3)

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to just add them, +

```
select 
[Created on],
[Created At],
LEFT([Created On],11),
RIGHT([Created At],8),
[Created On] + [Created At] as whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to do it, in my opinion, is to make use of how `datetime` is implemented by SQL Server: SQL Server implements a `datetime` value as a pair of signed 32-bit integers.

- The high-order word is the date component. It is the offset in days from the SQL Server's  epoch of 1 January 1900.
- The low-order word is the time component. It is the offset in milliseconds from start-of-day (00:00:00.000).

With that knowledge in hand, we can see the implementation thus:

```
select convert(binary(8),convert(datetime,'March 17, 2014'))
```

returns

```
0x0000A2F100000000
```

and

select convert(binary(8),convert(datetime,'17:55:23'))

returns

```
0x0000000001275CE4
```

So, to meld the date component of one `datetime` value with the time component of another:

```
convert(datetime,
    substring(convert(binary(8),date_only_column),1,4)
  + substring(convert(binary(8),time_only_column),5,4)
  )
```

Easy!

And to format as an ISO 8601 string:

```
convert(varchar(32),
  convert(datetime,
      substring(convert(binary(8),date_only_column),1,4)
    + substring(convert(binary(8),time_only_column),5,4)
    ) ,
    120 -- or 121 if your want milliseconds.
  )
```